# A question about saving a file in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xslt, domdocument

I've used the following code to do an XSLT in php:

```
 # LOAD XML FILE 
 $XML = new DOMDocument(); 
 $XML = simplexml_load_file("images/upload/source.xml");

 # START XSLT 
 $xslt = new XSLTProcessor(); 
 $XSL = new DOMDocument();  
 $XSL->load( 'xsl/transfer.xsl', LIBXML_NOCDATA); 
 $xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL ); 

 #PRINT   
 print $XML->saveXML();
 print $XML->save("newfile.xml") ;
```

The code is quite straightforward, we need to load the source xml file and then load up the stylesheet, and indeed it actually works.

The code that causes trouble is the last line:

```
print $XML->save("newfile.xml") ;
```

after running which I got error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::save() ". But, actually ,I was following a tutorial here:
http://devzone.zend.com/article/1713.

Maybe I screwed up something, could anybody give me a hint? thanks in advance.

Following your guys' advice, I modified the code like this:

```
 # LOAD XML FILE 
 $XML = new DOMDocument(); 
 $XML->load("images/upload/source.xml");

 # START XSLT 
 $xslt = new XSLTProcessor(); 
 $XSL = new DOMDocument();  
 $XSL->load( 'xsl/transfer.xsl', LIBXML_NOCDATA); 
 $xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL ); 

 #PRINT    
  print $xslt->transformToXML( $XML );
```

now the correctly-transformed XML gets shown in the browser, I've tried some ways but still couldn't figure out how to print this result to a file instead of showing in the browser, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing how `$XML` is defined, simply call the [`load`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) method on `$XML` instead of `simplexml_load_file`:

```
$XML = new DOMDocument(); 
$XML->load("images/upload/source.xml");
```

There's no reason at all to use `simplexml` since the XSLT processing is all done with DOMDocument.  So just replace that one line, and you should be good to go...

Answer (score 1):

```
$XML = new DOMDocument(); 
$XML = simplexml_load_file("images/upload/source.xml");
```

First you store a `DOMDocument` in `$XML`, and then you replace it with a `SimpleXMLElement`. `DOMDocument` does have a `save` method, but `SimpleXMLElement` does not.

Admission: didn't look at the tutorial, so I don't know why/if that one works.

Comment: I replaced my last two lines of code with "print $xslt->transformToXML( $XML )" , now the result after doing XSLT is corretly printed to the browser. What about I still want it to be print to a file?

Comment: @Robert: then use `$XML->asXML()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php.

Comment: This should have been a comment, since it only points out what's wrong, not how to fix it (not worth a -1 imho, but just stating)...

Comment: @ircmaxell: you could be right. The question only asks "what is wrong here?" though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$XML = new DOMDocument(); 
$XML = simplexml_load_file("images/upload/source.xml");
```

You're *saying* that `$XML` is a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domdocument.php) and then you replace it with a [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.simplexml.php) on line 2

Use

```
$XML = new DOMDocument(); 
$XML->load("images/upload/source.xml");
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

```
$XML = new DOMDocument(); 
$XML = simplexml_load_file("images/upload/source.xml");
```

You create a DOMDocument, which you then overwrite with a SimpleXMLElement object. The first line is dead code. You aren't using it at all, since you overwrite it in the next statement.

`save` is a method in `DOMDocument`. `asXML($file)` is the equivalent for SimpleXML (or `saveXML($file)` which is an alias.

If you look at the tutorial, it's clearly:

```
$xsl = new DomDocument();
$xsl->load("articles.xsl");
$inputdom = new DomDocument();
$inputdom->load("articles.xml");
```

So, if you use `simplexml_load_file`, then you're not really following the tutorial.